# How to auto authenticate to my web-service?

Tags: java, spring, windows, api, authentication

I have created a simple web service which provides some data through an API. I need the API to be password secured, but it will cause each request to the API URL's to prompt a authentication box (Username and password). I need it to be seamless, is there a way to configure the Username and Password data to be configured in the machine, so that it is auto authenticated on each request (even for the first request)?
I am using windows10 and my web service is made using Spring and Java. Thank you ;-)

Comment: u can use token, but still u must authenticate for the 1st time

Answer (score 1):

In this case you might consider utilising the headers so that you provide your auth mechanism in there, I strongly suggest Spring security and JWT tokens, here is an example of securing your API with spring security and JWT (https://medium.com/@hantsy/protect-rest-apis-with-spring-security-and-jwt-5fbc90305cc5)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to securing your apis there are many ways you can address this please  find some of the useful links

- [Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration)
- [OAuth 2.0](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce/?utm_campaign=text_website_all_multiple_dev_dev_oauth-pkce_null&utm_source=oauthio&utm_medium=cpc)
- [Spring security](https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring)